# Qt or PyQt - check when file is used by another process. Wait until finish copy

Tags: qt, copy, pyqt4, monitor

Good morning,
What is the best strategy for check when a big file o big directory has finished to copy?
I want wait until a file has finish fully to copy. Is there a code example in q

I'm working on mac os x.

thanks

**Update**

I use QFileSystemWatcher. the problem is that I receive file or directory change notification when o copy it is in progress. So user copy a big folder (inside many files), the operating system copy process start, it take 5 minuts, but in same times my application receive file changed notification. This is a problem because when i receive a change notification my application start for doing some operations on that files, but the copy is already in progress!!!!

Comment: FYI: i recently learned that QFileSystemWatcher (running on windows) works on network shares aswell if the servers run windows. It wont work correctly for network shares which run on a linux server with an old samba version - dunno if it does work correctly with an up to date samba version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the QFileSystemWatcher is the right start for you to get to the point of monitoring for changes, but as you have found, these changes are *ANY* changes. From this point, I think it should be easy enough for you to just check the modification time of the file.

Here is a simple example of a Watcher class that will let you specify a file to monitor and see if it has been modified after a given time. It can run a callback or emit a signal that anyone can watch:

```
import os.path
import time

from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Watcher(QtCore.QObject):

    fileNotModified = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    MOD_TIME_DIFF = 5 #seconds

    def __init__(self, aFile, callback=None, checkEvery=5):
        super(Watcher, self).__init__()

        self.file = aFile
        self.callback = callback

        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self._timer.setInterval(checkEvery*1000)
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self._checkFile)

    def _checkFile(self):
        diff = time.time() - os.path.getmtime(self.file)
        if diff > self.MOD_TIME_DIFF:
            self._timer.stop()

            self.fileNotModified.emit(self.file)

            if self.callback:
                self.callback()

    def start(self):
        self._timer.start()

    def stop(self):
        self._timer.stop()
```

An example of using it:

```
def callbackNotify():
    print "Callback!"

def signalNotify(f):
    print "Signal: %s was modified!" % f

# You could directly give it a callback
watcher = Watcher("/path/to/file.file", callback=callbackNotify)
# Or could use a signal
watcher.fileNotModified.connect(signalNotify)
# tell the watcher timer to start checking
watcher.start()

## after the file hasnt been modified in 5 seconds  ##
# Signal: /path/to/file.file was modified!
# Callback!
```

Answer (score 2):

There is only one reliable way to do this: Change the copy process to write to temporary files and then rename them after the copy is finished.

That way, you can ignore new files which end with `.tmp` and rename is an atomic operation.

If you can't change the copy process, all you can do is add a timer to wait for, say, half an hour to make sure the copy is really finished.

A more fine grained (and more risky) approach is to add a loop that check the file size and stops when the file size doesn't change for a certain time but that's also hard to get right.

Worse, this doesn't prevent you from reading partial files (when the copy process was terminated in the middle).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [QtConcurrent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qtconcurrent.html) framework.
In particular, check out QFuture and [QFutureWatcher](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfuturewatcher.html#details). You can execute asynchronous copy operations inside a QFuture object and monitor its progress through signals and slots with a watcher.

```
bool copyFunction() {
  // copy operations here, return true on success
}

MyHandlerClass myObject;
QFutureWatcher<bool> watcher;
connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &myObject, SLOT(handleFinished()));
QFuture<bool> future = QtConcurrent::run(copyFunction);
```

Comment: the problem is that it isn't my app that copy file but an external application. So, My application must wait until a external application finished copy to a directory that my application is monitoring for capture a change file or directory.

Comment: In this case you can use a QFileSystemWatcher: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemwatcher.html read notes carefully for platform specific issues

Comment: I use QFileSystemWatcher. the problem is that I receive file or directory change notification when o copy it is in progress. So user copy a big folder (inside many files), the operating system copy process start, it take 5 minuts, but in same times my application receive file changed notification. This is a problem because when i receive a change notification my application start for doing some operations on that files, but the copy is already in progress!!!!

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. If you don't have any control on the process which is copying file I'm afraid the only way is monitoring destination directory with something like lsof to know exactly what's going on. Or, if you know exactly *when* copyings occur, you could assume copy finished when your watcher stops emitting signals, but I fear this solution could be very unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no control on the external application, my suggestion is that you lock the files while you work on them. In this way other programs will not be able to access them while locked.

Alternatively, if you have access to the other program's source, you should implement some form of inter process communication,via sockets, messages or whatever method you prefer.